# libgdx + netty = краш

Tags: java, libgdx, netty

Я пытаюсь создать libgdx проект и мне необходим netty, но если я добавляю необходимую зависимость в проект программа крашится.
Вот весь код проекта:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
    config.setForegroundFPS(60);
    config.setTitle("hello world");
    new Lwjgl3Application(new GameLauncher(), config); // <- краш происходит здесь
}
```

gradle файл:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'

    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.12.0:natives-desktop"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.12.0"

    implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.90.Final'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Также я заметил что если убрать из зависимостей libgdx и оставить только netty, программа запускается нормально. Так что ошибка возникает при создании Lwjgl3Application только если эти две зависимости используются одновременно. В чем может быть проблема?
Кусок из крашлога:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000018d93b3ea90):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=12792, stack(0x0000004991800000,0x0000004991900000)]

Stack: [0x0000004991800000,0x0000004991900000],  sp=0x00000049918fba18,  free space=1006k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x1937e0]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(IIJJJJ)J+0
j  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(IIJJJ)J+14
j  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(IILjava/lang/CharSequence;JJ)J+34
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.createGlfwWindow(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;J)J+340
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.createWindow(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3Window;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;J)V+2
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.createWindow(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener;J)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3Window;+23
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.<init>(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;)V+243
j  Launcher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+32
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0xffffffffffffffff
```

GameLauncher - это полностью пустой класс расширяющий ApplicationAdapter (com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter) `public class GameLauncher extends ApplicationAdapter { }`
Я использую gradle 7.5.1

Comment: В приведенном коде проблем нет, все работает исправно. Возможно, проблема в классе `GameLauncher`, который вы не показали (если этот класс тянется из библиотеки, то покажите импорты). Почитайте, как сделать [mre]. Также укажите версию gradle, которую вы используете в проекте. Кроме этого, напишите в вопросе, как вы запускаете свою программу. Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: Вам нужно убедиться, что все используемые зависимости совместимы между собой и не противоречат друг другу. В случае с библиотеками libgdx и netty, возможно, они используют разные версии некоторых общих библиотек, что приводит к конфликтам